# Can a tall chain of mountains rise, apparently like the Sun, if watched from a plane approaching the mountains?

Tags: geometric-optics

Assuming you are in a passenger plane that flies at 11000 meters having a speed of 1000 km/h, and pointing to a chain of mountains 5000 m tall, is it possible to see the chain rising from below the horizon line like the Sun when half of its disc rises above the horizon in the morning.

Comment: Yes, it can. It can "rise" when sailing on a ship.

Comment: @mmesser314 , I am talking about rising fast, somehow like the Sun in the morning, not in one day. Anyway, according to the calculations and animations of this site ( http://walter.bislins.ch/bloge/index.asp?page=Advanced+Earth+Curvature+Calculator ) the mountains I am talking about can rise in about 20 minutes as seen from an ordinary plane and 10 minutes if watched from an approaching supersonic airliner like Concorde.